# Overload Constructor

Tags: java

I have this MyClass that has a 3 fields. But I need to change the datatype `info` into an object of `Info`, to accomodate 2 more fields. The String info, will be equivalent to `info.text`. But there is a lot if calls on the MyClass Constructor and we dont want to change it as the only required field is the `info.text.`. How can I overload the constructor? For some will call the new Constructor with an argument of object `Info` instead of String.

```
public class MyClass {
        
       private String status;
       private String reason;
       private String info;

        public MyClass(final String status, final String reason, final String info) {                                  
                this.status= status;
                this.reason= reason;
                this.info= StringUtils.trimToNull(info);
        }

}

@Getter
@Setter
public class Info {

   private String text;
   private String image;
   private String details;

}
```

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  You certainly can create another constructor with different parameters.  What happens when you do exactly that?

Comment: Just add another overloaded constructor if you want. You can have as many constructors in your class as you would like as long as they all have different signatures. Just add another one like: `public MyClass (Info info) { // Do what you want with the supplied instance of Info. }`

Comment: Any comments on the answers you got? If one of them answers your question, please consider accepting at some point.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, you probably want something like:

```
public class MyClass {       
   private String status;
   private String reason;
   private Info info;

    public MyClass(final String status, final String reason, final Info info) {                                  
            this.status= status;
            this.reason= reason;
            this.info = info;
    }
```

and

```
    public MyClass(final String status, final String reason, final String infoText) {                                  
            this(status, reason, new Info().setText(StringUtils.trimToNull(infoText));
    }
```

Meaning: you change your class to have an Info object, instead of an "Info" string. Then you allow to create your class by passing an Info object; but you keep the existing constructor, but you invoke the new one, and pass in an Info object that gets set up with the `text` property.

Of course that only works when your setters return the object they are setting. In case your setters have return type `void`, that "trick" to invoke the other constructor isn't possible, in that case you will end up with two very similar but slightly different bodies for the constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on GhostCat's answer. The way I understood it, you need to keep old constructor, getters and setters to support Legacy. You can replace the `String info` field, but still need its setter and getter. You can overload the `setInfo()` method and add a new getter for the new field. Also, the `Info` class needs to override the `toString()` method in the `Info` class to return a `String` formatted the same way that legacy code expects it.

```
public class MyClass {       
   private String status;
   private String reason;
   private Info info;

   // constructors

   public void setInfo(String info) {
      // convert String to Info and set in field
   }

   public String getInfo () {
      return info.toString(); // need to override toString() in Info class
   }

   // new getter and setter
   // Overloaded method (different param list)
   public void setInfo (Info info) {
      this.info = info;
   }

   // cannot use same name because param list is the same
   public Info getInfo2() {
      return info;
   }
}
```